# Rails 3 : Check if record correctly updated when remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using javascript(coffeescript) as format for the response to an update action.
I can't figure out how to check if the record has been successfully updated in my js.coffee response.

For create I use `.new_record?`, for destroy we have `.destroyed?` to check that the record has been created/destroyed correctly, what about update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If think the solution was too simple for me.
I can simply use `.errors.empty?`..

Answer (score 3):

What about returning different JSON objects, depending on the outcome of updating your object:

```
def update
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @foo.update_attributes(params[:foo])
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.json { render json: @foo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Client side, you'd inspect the status property on the returned object.

Comment: Good idea, so I guess there isn't any equivalent to `.new_record?` and `.destroyed?` for the update case?